# How to get Latitude and Longitude of any City using Google API and a form?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, google-maps-api-3

I am currently designing a project where I need to get the latitude and longitude of whatever city a user types in and once it is typed in, I have a button which once clicked is suppose to get the Latitude and Longitude of this city and put it in two textboxes I have set up. I am using the Google Places API and map as well in my project.

Any ideas of how I might accomplish this as I have been attempting to do this for over a week now.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the google [geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

I built [a simple example](http://jsbin.com/hoqezopibo/2/edit) on jsbin.

```
$("#city").on("change keyup", function() {
  var city = $(this).val()
  $.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+encodeURIComponent(city), function(val) {
    if(val.results.length) {
      var location = val.results[0].geometry.location
      $("#lat").val(location.lat)
      $("#lon").val(location.lng)
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a perfect example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)

```
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
if (place.geometry.viewport) 
  map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
else 
{
  map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
  map.setZoom(17);  //Or any zoom level
}
```

Just look at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details)

You'll have to adapt it to your need of course.
Just use the latitude and longitude given in `place.geometry` object returned.